# Clickhouse: sum of arrays based on another array

Tags: arrays, clickhouse

Say you have the following table:

```
ID  COUNTRIES                   UNITS
1   ['UK', 'Italy', 'France']   [2000, 1000, 1000]
1   ['France', 'Italy', 'UK']   [3000, 4000, 2000]
1   ['Italy']                   [2000]
```

Is there a way in ClickHouse to add up the `RATIOS` column for each country in the `COUNTRIES` column? Something like `sum(UNITS) group by COUNTRIES`

Expected result:

```
ID  COUNTRIES                   TOTAL_UNITS
1   ['UK', 'Italy', 'France']   [4000, 4000, 7000]
```

Reprex code:

```
SELECT data.1 ID, data.2 COUNTRIES, data.3 UNITS
FROM (
    SELECT arrayJoin([(1, ['UK', 'Italy', 'France'], [2000, 1000, 1000]), 
                    (1, ['France', 'Italy', 'UK'], [3000, 4000, 2000]), 
                    (1, ['Italy'], [2000])]) data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sumMap(COUNTRIES, UNITS) from (

SELECT data.1 ID, data.2 COUNTRIES, data.3 UNITS
FROM (
    SELECT arrayJoin([(1, ['UK', 'Italy', 'France'], [2000, 1000, 1000]), 
                    (1, ['France', 'Italy', 'UK'], [3000, 4000, 2000]), 
                    (1, ['Italy'], [2000])]) data)

)

┌─sumMap(COUNTRIES, UNITS)───────────────────┐
│ (['France','Italy','UK'],[4000,7000,4000]) │
└────────────────────────────────────────────┘




select (sumMap(COUNTRIES, UNITS) as x).1 a , x.2  b from (

SELECT data.1 ID, data.2 COUNTRIES, data.3 UNITS
FROM (
    SELECT arrayJoin([(1, ['UK', 'Italy', 'France'], [2000, 1000, 1000]), 
                    (1, ['France', 'Italy', 'UK'], [3000, 4000, 2000]), 
                    (1, ['Italy'], [2000])]) data)

)
┌─a───────────────────────┬─b────────────────┐
│ ['France','Italy','UK'] │ [4000,7000,4000] │
└─────────────────────────┴──────────────────┘




select groupArray(COUNTRY) COUNTRIES, groupArray(s) UNITS from (
select sum(UNIT) s, COUNTRY from (

SELECT data.1 ID, data.2 COUNTRIES, data.3 UNITS
FROM (
    SELECT arrayJoin([(1, ['UK', 'Italy', 'France'], [2000, 1000, 1000]), 
                    (1, ['France', 'Italy', 'UK'], [3000, 4000, 2000]), 
                    (1, ['Italy'], [2000])]) data)
) array join UNITS as UNIT, COUNTRIES as COUNTRY
group by COUNTRY)

┌─COUNTRIES───────────────┬─UNITS────────────┐
│ ['France','Italy','UK'] │ [4000,7000,4000] │
└─────────────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue in the same context and I solved it with this solution:

```
with cte  as(
       select arrayJoin(arrayZip(COUNTRIES, UNITS)) as t,
       t.1 as country,
       t.2 as units
       from your_table_name)
select country, sum(units) from cte group by country;
```